# as3 worker message issue

Tags: actionscript-3, worker

I found this example on as3 worker: http://esdot.ca/site/2012/intro-to-as3-workers-part-2-image-processing

it works great on air 3.4 but with greater versions it stops working, no error, or message. how to fix this?

and are there other example on image prcessing working with newer APis.

regards

Comment: As a matter of fact I tried this code example some time ago and it works just fine with the latest AIR versions. Now the way you describe your problem: "it stops working" do you really think an answer can come out of such a problem description? In code there are things that happen and things that should happen but don't, describe all of them from start to finish.

Comment: I compiled the example in cs6 with the newest air sdk. nothing, no error, nothing. I compiled it in CC15, the same.

Comment: ok, its working with th flash player, but air didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue with the WorkersAPI when ran on ADL (Android Debug Launcher)

Kindly check my recent post

[AS3 using Workers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33526437/as3-using-workers)

Answer (score 0):

fount it, the air20 package does not debug on this installation, I linked the airglobal.swc to debug this version.

one more issue: when I'm init the worker outside of the main constructor... nothing happens. why? I found no information on this...

Comment: Since you didn't just copied and pasted code but also followed the tutorial very carefully and now have a good understanding of the way this works you probably just forgot that the constructor has to run twice, once for the current (main) worker, and twice for the sub worker.